# Como crear un correo automaticamente en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

A la hora de ingresar los nombres y apellidos (materno y paterno) crear un correo con sus dos primeras letras. Ejemplo:

> Armando Casas Sanchez = arcasa@ejemplo.pe

Comment: Reformula la pregunta porque tu descripción y tu ejemplo no coinciden. Y lo que vas a necesitar es un trigger

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un update del campo email concatenando los valores de los nombres y apellidos y el dominio del email.

```
update nombretabla set email = concat(substr(nombre,1,2),substr(paterno,1,2),substr(materno,1,2),"@ejemplo.pe")
```